# How to transport data from csv to Excel

Tags: python, excel, list, csv, indexing

I've got 2 files.

**file1:**

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7585,10,11
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7585,10,11,12,14,15
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7585,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
```

**file2:**

```
0,1,2,3,4,5
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7585,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7585,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14
```

Im trying to export all the rows where index 10 == `7585` to Excel,
regardless of the lenght of the rows.

**This is my code:**

```
my_path = r'c:\data\EKL\Desktop\my-files' 

for file in os.listdir(my_path):
    path_file = os.path.join(my_path, file)
    with open(path_file, 'r') as output:
        reader = csv.reader(output, delimiter = ',')
        read = [row for row in reader if row] 
        for row in read:                  
                if row[10] == '7585':
                    print(','.join(row[0:]))
```

**This is my outcome:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\data\EKL\Desktop\Python\PythongMySQL\untitled2.py", line 14, in <module>
    if row[10] == '7585':

IndexError: list index out of range
```

**This is my desired outcome in an EXCEL worksheet:**

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7585,10,11
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7585,10,11,12,14,15
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7585,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7585,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7585,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import os
import csv

my_path = r'sof' # local path of csv files
index = 10 # index you would like to check
value = '7585' # value of the index it should be

for file in os.listdir(my_path):
    path_file = os.path.join(my_path, file)
    with open(path_file, 'r') as output:
        reader = csv.reader(output, delimiter = ',')
        read = [row for row in reader if row] 
        for row in read:               
            if len(row) >= index and row[index] == value:
                print(','.join(row[0:]))
```

#### Output

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7585,10,11
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7585,10,11,12,14,15
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7585,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7585,10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,7585,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22
```

#### Update - with Excel Export

```
import os
import csv
import xlsxwriter

my_path = r'sof' 
index = 10
value = '7585'

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Start from the first row
rown = 0

for file in os.listdir(my_path):
    path_file = os.path.join(my_path, file)
    with open(path_file, 'r') as output:
        reader = csv.reader(output, delimiter = ',')
        read = [row for row in reader if row] 
        for row in read:               
            if len(row) >= index and row[index] == value:
                worksheet.write_row("A"+str(rown+1),row)
                rown+=1

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Where is to excel part?

Comment: @TangerCity please mark the question as solved, if it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

Didn't check if it's running, but I'd try something like this:

```
my_path = r'c:\data\EKL\Desktop\my-files' 

for file in os.listdir(my_path):
    path_file = os.path.join(my_path, file)
    with open(path_file, 'r') as output:
        reader = csv.reader(output, delimiter = ',')
        read = [row for row in reader if row] 
        for row in read:                  
                if (len(row) > 10) and (row[10] == '7585'):  # add extra condition
                    print(','.join(row[0:]))
```

Comment: that part worked. Now how to get it in an Excel worksheet instead of printing it?

Comment: Sorry, I went for the quick-buck. :D I only checked the error and the traceback. @Stefan Shulz seems to have the correct answer.